# other error while trying to print the receipt using escposprinter python library in windows10

Tags: python, thermal-printer, escpos

I am developing hotel billing system that prints the bill receipt using thermal printer but i am stuck at
**[Errno None] Other errors**

python3.9
library: escposprinter &
libusb-1.0,
plateform:windows 10
Thermal printer: xlab xp-58III

```html
from escposprinter import *

try:
    Epson = printer.Usb(0x0416, 0x5011)
    Epson.text('Hello World')
    Epson.cut()
except Exception as e:
    print("PRINTER ERROR: ", e)
```

Result: [Errno None] Other errors
if i remove try block then, Result: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Can you provide your exact code? And the exact output? Also, your variable values aren't quoted.

Comment: If you have a serial port device driver provided by your printer vendor, you can try other libraries or use PySerial directly.

Comment: i have edited by post please i need suggestion